# Reading From File in Python

Tags: python, file, io

I was wondering if somebody could help me out with the following Python 3 code.  For some reason it is not doing what I believe it should be doing and I cannot understand why.

```
with open("ModuleShow.txt", "w+", encoding='utf-8') as ModuleShowFile:
            if ModulesLeft == 0:
                ModuleLoaded = CommandLine[2]
                print(ModuleLoaded)
            else:
                ModuleLoaded = ModuleToLoad[0]
                ModuleToLoad.pop(0)
                ModulesLeft = ModulesLeft - 1
                #            ModuleFile.write("\n" + ModuleLoaded)                                                    
                #            CommandsFile.write("module show" + ModuleLoaded)                                         
            output = subprocess.Popen(["bash", "-ci", "module show " + ModuleLoaded], stderr=ModuleShowFile)

#            with open("ModuleShow.txt", "r", encoding='utf-8') as ModuleShowFile:                                        

            print(ModuleShowFile.read())
            for ModuleFileLine in ModuleShowFile:
                FileLine = ModuleFileLine.split(" ")

                print(FileLine[0])
                if FileLine[0] == "prepend-path":
                    print(FileLine[0])
                    if FileLine[1] == "PATH":
                        ModulePathFile.write(FileLine[2] + " " + ModuleLoaded + "\n")
                    elif FileLine[0] == "module":
                        ModuleToLoad.append(FileLine[2])
                        ModulesLeft = ModulesLeft + 1
```

So what I am doing in the above code is writing information to a file called ModuleShow.txt and then parse that information and writing the parsed information to a file called ModulePath.txt, I opened the ModulePath.txt before, but I did not include that part of the code since I believe it is not related to the problem I am having.

So basically, when I run my script, the contents are written to the file, but I do not get anything when I read the contents.  For example, I tried using "print(ModuleShowFile.read())," but nothing prints yet the file gets created with the contents inside.  I tried having two "with open()" lines, one for writing and another for reading, but it still did not solve the problem.  Hopefully it is something simple and I apologize for the long post.  I would greatly appreciate any help.  Thank you.

Comment: When you tried it using a second `open()`, one for writing and a second for reading, did you close the first handle / leave the scope of the first `open()` context handler?  In other words, was the second `open()` indented an equal or lesser amount as the first?

Comment: The second open() was indented the same amount as the first open().

Answer (score 0):

Do you even need to write the file ModuleShow.txt?  Or can you just hold the entries in a list?

If you really need to read them back in again, close the file first, like this:

```
with open("ModuleShow.txt", "w+", encoding='utf-8') as ModuleShowFile:
    # ... whatever (I'm assuming you're writing to the file here)

# now the file is closed
with open("ModuleShow.txt", "r", encoding='utf-8') as ModuleShowFile:
    for ModuleFileLine in ModuleShowFile:
        # ... now you can read each line
```

Comment: I had tried that already and for some reason it did not work. I did keep on messing around with it and for some reason when I did the following I was able to get the output: 

    `with open("ModuleShow.txt", "w+", encoding='utf-8') as ModuleShowFile:` 
        `#...Code to write to file` 
        `output.communicate() # This is the only line I added from original post with`  
    `open("ModuleShow.txt", "r", encoding='utf-8') as ModuleShowFile:`  
        `print(ModuleShowFile.read())` 
        `#Rest of code from original post`

Comment: If my comment is hard to understand, I can edit my original post with the new code.  What I did is uncomment the second `with open` line and before that added the line `output.communicate()`.  Any idea why I am able to read the file after I use `output.communicate()`?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the bit about communicating with the subprocess.  I guess the subprocess hasn't quite finished yet, or hasn't flushed its output to the file.  Apparently a `wait()` or a `communicate()` makes sure that it has finished, but that's unknown territory for me.